# Proof clarification(an algebraic geometric doubt): a torsor of an elliptic curve is a twist

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, elliptic-curves

From Silverman's AEC page 323 (Chapter 10, section 3 on Homogeneous Spaces), the proof of the following fact (Proposition 3.2, part (a)):

Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve and let $C/K$ be a homogeneous space for it. Fix a point $p_0 \in C$, define a map $$ \theta: E \rightarrow C,     \theta(P) = p_0+P. $$
for all $P \in E$.

The proof says that if the point $p_0$ is fixed by the Galois group, $G_{\bar{K}/K}$ then $\theta$ is defined over $K$. Hence $\theta$ is defined over $K(p_0)$. Further, it says that

**Since the action of $E$ on $C$ is simple transitive, degree of $\theta$ is one** hence it's an isomorphism.

Could someone help elaborate on the statement in bold, which is the only part of the proof I don't understand. As far as I insert, showing the degree of the map $\theta$ means that $[\bar{K}(E) : \phi^*(\bar{K}(C))] =1$, but I don't know how to relate it with the action of $E$ on $C$.

Any help towards the clarification will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you tell me why $θ$ is a morphism ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simply transitive group action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is one so that for any $x,y\in X$, there is exactly one $g\in G$ so that $gx=y$. Thus the fiber of $\theta$ over any point is a single point, and so the map must be of separable degree one. This is enough to prove the claim in the case when the underlying field has characteristic zero, since the only nontrivial inseparable extensions are in characteristic $p$. This may suffice for some readers, since this is the setting in which Silverman uses these results later on in the book (Mordell-Weil is about abelian varieties over number fields, aka finite extensions of $\Bbb Q$).

In characteristic $p$, there is more to say. It may be that a map of curves with separable degree one is not an isomorphism: the $k$-linear Frobenius is an example. On the other hand, over a perfect field, this is the only thing that can go wrong. By tag [0CCZ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CCZ), if $f:X\to Y$ is a purely inseparable map of proper regular curves over $k$ with $X$ smooth over $k$, then $f:X\to Y$ is uniquely isomorphic to $F_{X/k}^n:X\to X^{(p^n)}$, the $n$-fold relative Frobenius over $k$. If $k$ is perfect, then $X\cong X^{(p)}$ since the absolute Frobenius on $k$ is an isomorphism and $X^{(p)}\to k$ is defined to be the base change of $X\to k$ along the absolute Frobenius on $k$. This implies that given a map $E\to C$ as in the problem, we may factor this map as $E\to E^{(p^n)}\to C$ by factoring the field extension $K(C)\subset K(E)$ in to separable and inseparable parts followed by identifying $E^{(p^n)}$ with $E$ to find a separable map $E\to C$ with all the same properties. (Note that the base field was assumed perfect in the introduction to the section, so we can use this argument.)

This doesn't completely make the issue go away, though. For instance, on any elliptic curve $X$ over a perfect field with Hasse invariant 0 the map $X\times X\to X$ given by $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_1+[p]x_2$ fits the definition of a homogeneous space but not the conclusions of the theorem as written. My guess is that this was an oversight, but it's not mentioned in the [errata](https://www.math.brown.edu/johsilve/AEC/AECErrata.pdf). If anyone feels inclined to email Professor Silverman and obtain an explanation, I would welcome hearing about it in the comments.

Comment: But isn't the result we know is: for a nomconstant map of smooth curves, $\theta: C_1 \rightarrow C_2$, for all but finitely many $Q \in C_2$, $ \# \phi^{-1}(Q) =deg_{s}(\phi)$? (Silverman AEC page 24) could you explain how you got the result you stated from this because as far as I understand, we don't know if this map is separable or unramified here.

Comment: The post has been updated. Silverman assumes that $K$ is perfect (introduction to 10.2) which implies the result.

Comment: What do you mean by 'closed points'? Do you mean 'all but finitely many points in $C$?

Comment: If you're not using schemes, I mean "all the points in $C$".

Comment: Could you tell me why $θ$ is a morphism ?

Comment: @kleinfour this is assumed as part of the definition of what it means for $C$ to be a homogeneous space for $E$ - check the introduction to the subsection in question for details.

Comment: From definition of homogeneous spaces, we know C×E→C is a morphism, but how do you prove from this that $θ:E→C$ is a morphism ?

Comment: @kleinfour this is the composite of $C\times E\to C$ with the inclusion $\{p_0\}\times E\to C\times E$.

Comment: Thank you !  I think perfectness of fied $K$ does not guarantee that it' s function field $K(C)$ is perfect. Why can we say map $φ$:$E→C$ is separable  ?

Comment: @KReiser So I think modification are needed. If I'm misunderstnding, I'm glad if you could commet about avove issue.

Comment: @kleinfour sorry to have missed your comment. Someone else asked me about this recently and I figured I'd better go back and edit this - it does turn out that $E\cong C$ but potentially not by the map specified in the definition of a homogeneous space. See the edit.